# Retrieving last number (not index) of an a array - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I have this simple code below working perfectly.
It's retrieving data out of my database nicely.

The thing is, i need to retrieve the last number(not index) that is showing in the "saleNumber" row.
I'm gonna use it to increment the number of a form input text automatically.

I've tried to use end and array_slice in dozens of differents ways but could find a solution for this.

```
        <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<td class='contentTd'> $row[saleNumber] </td>
              <td class='contentTd'> $row[saleValue] </td>
              <td class='contentTd'> $row[paymentMethod] </td>
              <td class='contentTd'> $row[sellerName] </td>";
        };
```

I appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but why not just remember the value as you iterate through the loop, then use it?

```
<?php
$last = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $last = $row['saleNumber'];
    echo "<td class='contentTd'> $row[saleNumber] </td>
          <td class='contentTd'> $row[saleValue] </td>
          <td class='contentTd'> $row[paymentMethod] </td>
          <td class='contentTd'> $row[sellerName] </td>";
};
if (null !== $last) {
    $next = $last + 1; // or whatever
    echo "<td class='contentTd'> $next </td>...";

}
```

Comment: Thanks bishop! That did it!
But even now that is working, i don't understand how the $last variable gets only the last number and not an array of numbers.

Comment: Each time through the loop, `$last` is assigned the _scalar_ value of `$row['saleNumber']`. Had the code read `$last[] = $row['saleNumber']`, then it would be an array.

Comment: Got it! So simple yet i couldn't get it working. Thanks again!